# Python 3 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Start'

Tags: python, int

I am working with python 3.6.8, and I am passing a file in argument which has this structure:

```
Chr     Start       End 
chr4    153245445   153245445
```

I have received this error:

```
 **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Start'**
```

it seems it is coming from the line: `pos =int(line[1]) - 1`

```
def anno(o):
    "annotate vcf file, adding basic infomations into INFO columns"

    rep_ref = {}
    if o.repeat is not None: 
        ## adding human genome's repeat region reference, mutation around repeat region is usually suspectable
        with open(o.repeat) as rep:
            rep_line = rep.rstrip().split('\t')
            rep_ref[rep_line[0]] = (rep_line[1], rep_line[2])

    mutation = {}
    variation_info = {}

    LastChr = ''
    LastPos = 0

    with open(o.query) as fin:
        # vcf file
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
            chr = line[0]
            try:
                pos =int(line[1]) - 1
            except:
                raise Exception("vcf header should be expluded", o.query)

            if chr != LastChr:
                LastPos = pos
                LastChr = chr

            else:
                if pos < LastPos:
                    raise Exception("vcf ", o.query, " is unsorted!\n", 'chr: ', chr, "pos: ", LastPos, pos)
                LastPos = pos
```

Can you help me figure out what is causing this error? Thank you in advance

Comment: Check the string you are trying to convert to an integer. It seems to contain 'start', instead of digits.

Comment: You might need to skip the first line of the file - it looks like it's getting parsed as the integer, which you can do via a dummy `fin.readline()` at the beginning of the `with` block.

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message? Is that data tab delimited? By the way, why are mixing different variable naming conventions? Also, please provide a [mcve] as well as the **entire** error message.

Comment: @Member2017: re. your edit: did you just add "Thank you in advance" to a question that seem to lack it? Read [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) (spoiler alert: the answer is "Yes"; therefore *adding* it doubly-wrong).

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy, thanks for advice. I am kinda of newbie in python. Should i add fin.readline() just after with open(o.query) as fin: ? Thx

Comment: @AMC, yes my file is tab delimited. The error messge is only:  **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Start'**

Comment: @user979974 _yes my file is tab delimited._ Use the csv module or Pandas, it will make things much simpler! :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like homework which you don't understand. I suggest doing a bit more research into how file reading works. That said, in the post you say: "... I passing a file in argument which has this structure:"

```
Chr     Start       End 
chr4    153245445   153245445
```

You then read the file with:

```
with open(o.query) as fin:
    # vcf file
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        chr = line[0]
        try:
            pos =int(line[1]) - 1
        except:
            raise Exception("vcf header should be expluded", o.query)
```

On the first pass through the loop, line will contain "Chr     Start       End". After you clean it up and split it into its parts, line[1] will be "Start". An error - specifically a ValueError - will occur when you try to convert that to an integer.

As noted by @greencloakguy in a comment, you need to get past that header line, which you can do by inserting a readline between the with statement and the for loop.

```
with open(o.query) as fin:
    # vcf file
    fin.readline()
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
```

Comment: Hi @GreenMatt, thanks for your help. Actually, it is not a homework, it is just I am very newbie in Python. Thanks to your help I don't have the error but I have a new one for read in sam:
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Comment: It's good you made progress. That error indicates that you are trying to iterate over something that has Python's `None` as a value. If you haven't already figured it out, you might consider posting another question.